# Struts2 Row Update In an Iterator

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I am displaying my `List` by iterator in `Employee.jsp` as shown

**`Employee.jsp`:**

```
<thead>
    <tr >

    <td class=trusteditems>PFNO</td>
    <td class=trusteditems>Employee Name</td>
    <td class=trusteditems>Category</td>
    <td class=trusteditems>Password</td>
    <td class=trusteditems>Depot Code</td>      
    </tr>
</thead>

<s:iterator value="employelist" var="employemaster" status="status">
<tr >
<td><s:radio name="selectedCode" list="{#status}" value=""/></td>
<td><s:textfield disabled="true"  value="%{pfno}" size="15" name="pfno" 
style="text-   transform: uppercase" maxlength="8" theme="simple"/></td>
<td><s:textfield disabled="true"  value="%{name}" size="15" name="name" maxlength="8"  
theme="simple"/></td>
<td><s:textfield disabled="true"  value="%{type}" size="15" name="type"
 maxlength="8" theme="simple"/></td>
 style="text-transform: uppercase" maxlength="8" theme="simple"/></td>
<td><s:textfield disabled="true"  value="%{depocode}" size="15" name="depocode" 
style="text-transform: uppercase" maxlength="8" theme="simple"/></td>
<td><s:submit/></td>
<td></td>

</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

and i added a submit button at last. I want this submit button to carry that particular row to a Update `.jsp` page to update..
On clicking the submit in a particular row I want that particular row to carry to an another jsp called Update `.jsp`

Comment: What is a unique key field of the row?

Comment: Roman C .. The primary key if "pfno"

Answer (score 0):

You can't submit them to the action because you need the [`s:form` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/form-tag.html). It should be mapped to the action that will process fields submitted and return the result for`Update.jsp`.

It would be better if you use indexed property names to filter selected rows from submitted results like `name="employeList[%{#status.index}].pfno"`.

Make sure Struts [type conversion](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/type-conversion.html) is configured properly to allow populating a collection of beans.